# Manually installing culmus

Tags: installing, culmus

I am trying to understand better how to install the culmus package on a Mac OS X system with TeX Live (and not MikTeX).

I downloaded the non-executable format of this fonts bundle (found [here](https://www.ma.huji.ac.il/%7Esameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html) under "Download and Installation").

Taking a look at the unzipped files, the bundle contains font definition files (`.fd`) and font files (`.afm`, `.t3` and `vf` files) in a file hierarchy that fits the TeX Directory Structure scheme.

Now, the bundle includes a directory called `miktex` (that includes the file `updmap.cfg`).

I don't have this `miktex` directory in my `texmf` tree (since I use TeX Live).

Where, them, should I place this `updmap.cfg` file to complete the installation?

Comment: The cfg contains only two map lines `map culmus.map map culmusnkd.map` you can execute that with `updmap-sys --enable Map=culmus.map` and similar for the second map. Or add them simply to your document with `\pdfmapfile{culmus.map}`. (but I have some doubts that everything still works, this is all quite unmaintained, better use lualatex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your reply. I generally prefer working with XeLaTeX together with otf and ttf files, but for the moment I need to solve this problem. When you say "execute with `updmap-sys --enable Map=culmus.map`", could you elaborate on what does the command updmap-sys does, essentially? I want to understand the installation progress better, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

culmus-latex was originally written for linux. Since Mac OS X is also a Unix based system i think you will be able to install the original version of culmus-latex instead of the one written specifically for MikTeX and Windows.

The original version can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/), the installation instructions are in the README file.